# OpenGL 4 providing data to vertex buffer

Tags: c++, opengl, vertex-buffer, opengl-4

I use old way to provide the data to vertex buffer in OpenGL

```
glGenBuffers(1, buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(pos), pos, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
```

Since OpenGL 4.3 there a new slightly more clear way to provide data to vertex shader appears

```
const GLfloat colors[] =
{
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
};
glBindVertexBuffer(1, buffer, 0, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat));

glVertexAttribFormat(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0);
glVertexAttribBinding(1, 1);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
```

but I can't find any resources explaining how to provide data using new way. Of course I can do like this

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(colors), colors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); //i can do even so, and later I can use glBindVertexBuffer
```

but it looks not really elegant. If I will not use glBindBuffer and only use glBindVertexBuffer and then use glBufferData, I'll overwrite data in buffer that was bind using glBindBuffer. 

So question is: can I provide data to vertex buffer other way or I should always use glBindBuffer, glBufferData and only after that use glBindVertexBuffer,  glVertexBufferFormat, glVertexAttribFormat and glVertexAttribBinding. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can tell from the OpenGL 4.3 specification, you will still need to bind the vertex buffer to a "regular" binding point in order to update its data:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, offset, size, data);
```

This problem has effectively been solved in the 4.5 specification with the introduction of DSA functions, which allow you to update the buffer data without binding it to a slot first:

```
glNamedBufferSubData(buffer, offset, size, data);
```

Answer (score 4):

glVertexAttribFormat and glVertexAttribBinding are telling OpenGL *how* the data is organized in the buffer; essentially they replace glVertexAttribPointer (and *only* glVertexAttribPointer). Loading the data still happens with glBuffer[Sub]Data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But anyway to use glBufferData I should bind the buffer using glBindBuffer before, or exist other way to tell OpenGL that I want put data into buffer which I bind using glBindVertexBuffer (using both glBindBuffer just to put data and glBindVertexBuffer later seems little ambiguous to me)?